# Magento 2 - Change order status to 'Complete' using observer

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, order-status

I am using **sales_order_save_after** event to change order status. It's working fine for all order status except **STATE_COMPLETE**. when i set the order status **STATE_COMPLETE** to make order **Complete** but it changed to **Closed** instead of being **Complete**. Other order States is working fine. The issue only happening when i try to use *STATE_COMPLETE*.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
       if($order->getState() != 'complete') {
            $order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
            $order->save();
       }
}
```

This is what i'm doing

Can anyone help me out to make order status to "Complete" via observer ?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was when i set **STATE_COMPLETE** Magento make the order closed. But if i set **STATE_PROCESSING** or **STATE_PENDING** with status Complete then order status show complete but when i view the order details there it show processing/pending. So i tried to figure out when magento make order status complete and it is when a invoice is generated.

So i use **checkout_submit_all_after** event and create an invoice through my observer. When i create invoice through my observer magento make the order completed because the invoice is generated.

Here's the observer code -

```
class CheckoutSubmitAllAfter implements ObserverInterface{

protected $_invoiceService;
protected $_transactionFactory;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
  \Magento\Framework\DB\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory
) {
   $this->_invoiceService = $invoiceService;
   $this->_transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    try {
        if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
            return null;
        }
        if(!$order->getState() == 'new') {
            return null;
        }

        $invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
        $invoice->register();

        $transaction = $this->_transactionFactory->create()
          ->addObject($invoice)
          ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

        $transaction->save();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
        $order->save();
        return null;
    }
}}
```

Comment: where did you set order status to 'complete'?

Comment: You don't have to set it. It will be complete automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code:

```
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    if($order->getState() != Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {

        $orderState = Order::STATE_COMPLETE;

        // set order status to COMPLETE
        $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);

        // Save order
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

**Hope it Works!**

Comment: Not working order status showing closed

Comment: @RaselUddin can you change order status to complete by manually for any single order and check what status it displays.

Comment: If i manually change it show complete

Comment: @RaselUddin can you please check order status in backend Stores->Settings->Order Status.

Comment: yes everything is fine there. Please see i answered my ques how i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take note that invoking the the `save` method of the order would trigger a state check which might explain why you are experiencing the issue.

Magento 2 has a separate class for checking the order state.

In the  `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order` class you will find the save method invoking state check

```
public function save(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $object */
        $this->stateHandler->check($object);
        return parent::save($object);
    }
```

The `stateHandler` is an instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State`

I would recommend that you have a look that the method "check" to trace the logic flow.

You could either override the method `check` or create a plugin `aroundCheck` to change the state logic flow